# Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am moving my MVC website to a new 2012 server. Upon setting it up I installed MVC 3/4 and moved all my files over.  The website comes up which is great but whenever I go to a page that has a select list item for a dropdown I get the below error, why?

> Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>

Am I missing something I need to install on the server?  On my old server, it works fine.

if I comment the below in my controller the page comes up fine.

```
switch (model.QuestTest.NonLicensed) {
    case 0:
        model.QuestTest.NonLicensedDD.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "0-Non-licensed not available", Value = "0", Selected = true });
        model.QuestTest.NonLicensedDD.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1-Non-licensed available", Value = "1" });
        break;
    case 1:
        model.QuestTest.NonLicensedDD.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "0-Non-licensed not available", Value = "0" });
        model.QuestTest.NonLicensedDD.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1-Non-licensed available", Value = "1", Selected = true });
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: If you don't show us the code in question then we can't help you answer it. Also, why tag multiple versions of MVC? Which one are you *actually* using?

Comment: I am using mvc 4, sorry,  I got click happy.